# Home Exterior sheething

Tags: house-wrap, osb

I live in Michigan. My house was built in 1987 with 1/2" foil faced foam used as the sheething behind the vinyl siding (no house wrap). The fiberglass insulation in the walls is also faced. I'm getting ready to redo the siding and windows. I plan to put osb & house wrap on, as the foam board is not in good shape and the walls were built on 24" ctrs, so the siding is waving (need more nail points).

That said, would it be acceptable to put osb directly over the foil foam board with tyvek on the outside, or will that create a trapped wall with too many vapor barriers? I really don't want to have try and pull off all that foam board in millions of pieces.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tyvek is very specifically an air barrier, NOT a vapor barrier.